# Access Google Cloud Data using VSIGS

Tags: gdal, virtual-field

I want to access landsat data from gcp-public-data-landsat bucket using vsigs . My code looks like ,

```
import os, sys
from osgeo import gdal

print(gdal.VersionInfo('–version'))
print(sys.version)

url = "/vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/044/034/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2_B1.TIF"

gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_CURL_VERBOSE', 'YES')
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_DEBUG', 'YES')
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS', '.TIF')
gdal.SetConfigOption('GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '123123')
gdal.SetConfigOption('GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'blablabla')
src = gdal.Open(url)
print(gdal.Info(src))
```

But it shows

```
GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28
3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-5aadfee561e4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/souvik/Desktop/Final_Year_Project/google auth/untitled0.py', wdir='/home/souvik/Desktop/Final_Year_Project/google auth')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/souvik/Desktop/Final_Year_Project/google auth/untitled0.py", line 52, in <module>
    src = gdal.Open(url)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 3242, in Open
    return _gdal.Open(*args)

RuntimeError: `/vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/044/034/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2_B1.TIF' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

I also tried using rasterio , but it also shows parsed path problem. Also I have seen https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/vsigs.py .But could not figure out. Please tell to acsess it simply using GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID .

Comment: You haven't included the debug text. If you don't see it, can you try running the code outside spyder (i.e. via the command line).

Answer (score 1):

"`/vsigs`" doesn't use the full URL, just pass `/vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/path/to/file.tif`

For example:

```
import os, sys
from osgeo import gdal

print(gdal.VersionInfo('–version'))
print(sys.version)

url = "/vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/044/034/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2_B1.TIF"

gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_CURL_VERBOSE', 'YES')
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_DEBUG', 'YES')
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS', '.TIF')
gdal.SetConfigOption('GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '23412341234123412341234')
gdal.SetConfigOption('GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'blahblah')
src = gdal.Open(url)
print(gdal.Info(src))
```

Output:

```
GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14
3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00) 

#### DEBUG text ####
*   Trying 2404:6800:4006:809::2010...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to storage.googleapis.com (2404:6800:4006:809::2010) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: osgeo/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.storage.googleapis.com
*  start date: Jan 29 21:59:39 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 22 21:59:39 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "storage.googleapis.com" matched cert's "*.googleapis.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /gcp-public-data-landsat/?delimiter=%2F&prefix=LC08%2F01%2F044%2F034%2FLC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com
Accept: */*

#### I've truncated the DEBUG text ####

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/044/034/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2_B1.TIF
       /vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/044/034/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2_MTL.txt
Size is 7511, 7421
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32610"]]
Origin = (332385.000000000000000,4258815.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  METADATATYPE=ODL
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  332385.000, 4258815.000) (124d55'16.12"W, 38d27'42.87"N)
Lower Left  (  332385.000, 4036185.000) (124d52'13.76"W, 36d27'22.62"N)
Upper Right (  557715.000, 4258815.000) (122d20'18.02"W, 38d28'32.86"N)
Lower Right (  557715.000, 4036185.000) (122d21'20.87"W, 36d28' 9.14"N)
Center      (  445050.000, 4147500.000) (123d37'17.21"W, 37d28'21.92"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: It gives error in my case sir. RuntimeError: `/vsigs/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/044/034/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2/LC08_L1GT_044034_20130330_20170310_01_T2_B1.TIF' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

Comment: Please edit your question and run the edited code in my answer (replacing the GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID values with your actual values).  Please include the *full* output of the code, especially including the debug text (please censor your GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID from the debug text).

Comment: I have edited my question sir.